# How can I loop through 100+ text files and copy data between 'start' and 'end' from each

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to copy data from 100+ text files, all of which have two anchors, which is a row with 'Start' and another row with 'End'.  I want to grab these two anchor points, as well as all data in between these, and copy/paste everything to a single text file.

The code below copies data between the 'Start' and 'End', but these two anchors are getting dropped off.  Finally, I would like to write the name of the open text file after the 'End'.  Here is my sample code.

```
import os

directory = 'C:\\my_path_in\\all_files\\'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory + filename) as infile, open('C:\\my_path_out\\AllData.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        copy = False
        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() == 'START':
                copy = True
            elif line.strip() == 'END':
                copy = False
            elif copy:
                outfile.write(line)
```

In the example above, I would like to write the following to 'AllData.txt'

```
START
Store_Code
Sector
Zone
Zip
END
lamr.txt
```

Then, keep looping through all files and keep appending to AllData.txt

This was my final and working, solution.

```
import os
directory = 'C:\\Users\\rshuell\\Desktop\\all_files\\'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory + filename) as infile, open('C:\\Users\\rshuell\\Desktop\\AllData.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        try:
            print(filename)
            data = infile.readlines()
            outfile.write(filename+"\n"+"".join(data[data.index('START-OF-FIELDS\n'):data.index('END-OF-FIELDS\n')+1])+filename+"\n")
            infile.close()
            outfile.close()
        except:
            print(filename + ' is throwing an error')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and End aren’t written to the file. when a line equals to Start or End, the loop continues and never gets to the “elif copy” statement.

You can fix this by adding outfile.write(“Start”) after you set copy to true, and another one when you set copy to false.

To add the name of the opened file after every “end” : write to “outfile” the name of the file every time your are done copying a file.

Comment: OP does not want to write START or END to the file, they just want to get everything between the flags.

Comment: @probat no OP does want START/END look at his desired output and he stated the problem with his current code is that it cuts that off.

Comment: perhaps you are right, I figured they just included that as an example of what the input file looks like it.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this? if you use the built in readlines() function, it produces all the lines of a text file as a list. You can then find the index of the list that contains 'start' and 'end' and slice the lines list and rewrite it out to a new file

```
import os
directory = 'C:\\my_path_in\\all_files\\'
create_file = open('AllData.txt', 'w')

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close() 
    start = [lines.index(line) for line in lines if 'start' in line.lower()][0]
    end = [lines.index(line) for line in lines if 'end' in line.lower()][0]
    copy = lines[start:end+1]
    for line in copy:
        create_file.write(line)
    create_file.write(str(file))
```

Comment: Asem Okbys answer runns faster. He only needs to go troug every line once instead of 2-3 times the amount.

Comment: Hello there Anna.  I'm testing your code and getting this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AllData.txt'
The file is definitely in the directory.  I think the problem is that it is a text file, and as it's being read it's being written to.  That's why I put this summary file outside the folder with all the text files.  How can I modify my code to get the lines with 'START' and 'END'.  My code works, fine, but it's getting everything between these two anchor points?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you running this on mac?

Comment: @asher i removed the directory from where it's writing the AllData.txt file, it will save this file in the same location as your python script but it will at least ensure it always finds it. try running it now and let me know